# sed match on first instance not working

Tags: bash, sed

I want to replace the first instance of `<tr>` with `<tr class="active">` using the shell (bash).

However, this sed has no affect:

```
sed '0,/<tr>/s/<tr>/<tr class="active">/' FILE1 >> temp2.txt
```

temp2.txt remains

```
<tr>
  <th>set</th>
  <th>Run</th>
  <th>Continuum<br>filter</th>
  <th>Narrow Band<br>filter</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><a href="#set1">1</a></td>
  <td>Run09</td>
  <td>R_Harris</td>
  <td>6605/32</td>
</tr>
```

Whereas this code changes both the first and second instance of `<tr>`

```
sed '1,/<tr>/s/<tr>/<tr class="active">/' FILE1 >> temp2.txt
```

Can anyone explain what's going on?

```
<tr class="active">
    <th>set</th>
    <th>Run</th>
    <th>Continuum<br>filter</th>
    <th>Narrow Band<br>filter</th>
</tr>
<tr class="active">
    <td><a href="#set1">1</a></td>
    <td>Run09</td>
    <td>R_Harris</td>
    <td>6605/32</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: you first code seems to be working for me.

Comment: Try with different sed delimiter `sed '0,/<tr>/s~<tr>~<tr class="active">~' file`

Comment: Has no effect for me. This is strange. sed '0... replaces nothing, whilst sed '1... replaces the first and second instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following command.

```
sed -e '1,/<tr>/ s/<tr>/<tr class="active">/'
```

This command will substitute < tr > with < tr class="active" >

from line number 1 to first line < tr > found.

Comment: This is identical to my second attempt, without the -e flag. Could you tell me why without the flag, the first AND second instances get replaced?

Comment: oh no, it didn't work... this is very frustrating! Both the first and second instances of tr are still being changed...

Comment: OMG. I think I found the reason. is your input file "FILE1" starts with the first line <tr> ? if then, try your 2nd attempt again after insert a line at the beginning of the input file.

Comment: 1,/<tr>/ seems to cover the 1st line and next occurrence of <tr> after the 1st line.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below sed command,

```
$ sed '0,/<tr>/{s/<tr>/<tr class=\"active\">/}' file
<tr class="active">
  <th>set</th>
  <th>Run</th>
  <th>Continuum<br>filter</th>
  <th>Narrow Band<br>filter</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><a href="#set1">1</a></td>
  <td>Run09</td>
  <td>R_Harris</td>
  <td>6605/32</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: sed: 1: "0,/<tr>/{s/<tr>/<tr cla ...": bad flag in substitute command: '}'

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
sed '0,/\<tr\>/s/tr/tr class=\"active\"/' FILE1 >> temp2.txt
```

or you can edit FILE1 in place with:

```
sed -i '0,/\<tr\>/s/tr/tr class=\"active\"/' FILE1
```

output:

```
alchemy:~/scr/tmp/stack/dat> sed '0,/\<tr\>/s/tr/tr class=\"active\"/' table.html
<tr class="active">
  <th>set</th>
  <th>Run</th>
  <th>Continuum<br>filter</th>
  <th>Narrow Band<br>filter</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><a href="#set1">1</a></td>
  <td>Run09</td>
  <td>R_Harris</td>
  <td>6605/32</td>
</tr>
```

regarding your invalid command, the `0,/regex/s/this/to_that/' syntax will do the following compared to '1,/regex...'

```
0,addr2
Start  out  in  "matched  first  address"  state, until addr2 is found.  This 
is similar to 1,addr2, except that if addr2 matches the very first line of 
input the 0,addr2 form will be at the end of its range,  whereas  the 1,addr2 
form will still be at the beginning of its range.  This works only when addr2 
is a regular expression.
```

copying your input to table2.html and using the `sed -i` form results in the following:

```
$ sed -i '0,/\<tr\>/s/tr/tr class=\"active\"/' table2.html
$ cat table2.html
<tr class="active">
  <th>set</th>
  <th>Run</th>
  <th>Continuum<br>filter</th>
  <th>Narrow Band<br>filter</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><a href="#set1">1</a></td>
  <td>Run09</td>
  <td>R_Harris</td>
  <td>6605/32</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Using the sed -i, I got sed: 1: "FILE1": invalid command code F

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/<tr>/{s//<tr class="active">/;:a;n;ba}' file
```

Replace the first occurance and then do nothing with the rest of the file.

Or:

```
sed ':a;$!{N;ba};s/<tr>/<tr class="active">/' file
```

Slurp in the whole file and replace the first occurance.

Comment: sed: 1: "/<tr>/{s//<tr class="ac ...": unexpected EOF (pending }'s) for the first sed

Comment: the second still isn't changing the file :(

Comment: If I remove the { and } from the first one, it changes both the first and second instance of <tr>... maybe there is something wrong with FILE1

Comment: @liz_ophiuchus as per the first comment: the sed command should be surrounded by single quotes not double.